# On printf, fill content with char size

Tags: c++, c

lets say that I have the following variable:

> char name[20];

and lets say that its contents is this:

> strcpy(name, "test");

How do I print it with all 20 characters (print blank spaces after `\0`)?

When I print a float, by default it will fill some zeros after the dot (ie. 1.3000).

Can I do something similar with strings?

I've tried using `%.*s` and passing its size as first argument, but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `std::setw`. Also note that `.` is for precision, not width.

Comment: Do you have to use `printf`?

Comment: `printf("%-20s", name);`

Comment: @chris, `std::setw` seems to fill the content before.. I want to fill after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *C++* it looks like a combination of [std::left](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) and [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) will do what you would like. I added [std::setfill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) in the example to show the filled in characters:

```
std::cout << std::setw(20) <<  std::left << std::setfill('*') << name  <<  std::endl ;
```

For *C* with [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) as Matt points out the following will work:

```
printf("%-20s\n", name) ;
```